# How to change the backgroundimage property of a user control in a form app where the image is saved in the Resource folder?

Tags: vb.net

I am coding a game of Noughts and Crosses in a Windows Form Application using VB.NET. I want to display the symbols ("X" and "O") by adding a user control to the solution and changing its backgroundimage property to the appropriate symbol each time someone plays based off a boolean variable which is used to determine whose turn it is. The symbols are stored as .png files in the resources folder of the solution.

What is the syntax for changing the backgroundimage property?

I've got as far as:

'''Symbol1.BackgroundImage = '''

after that I do not know how to set it to a specific image located in the resources folder.

Any help appreciated.
Please ask if not clear enough.

Comment: As always in life, I found the answer immediately after posting the question. Apologies.

Comment: You can answer your own question and later accept the answer or you can delete your question.